# I used nginx rewrite to redirect from old URL to new URL, now curl GET and POST requests to old URL don't work

Tags: nginx, curl, nginx-config

I have a service running on https://old-server.net:8444/devs/. I set up a new service on a new server https://new-server.net/. When accessing the new service via the web, things work as expected. But when trying to login to the old service via curl (A POST request) or download from it (GET request), I just get the "301 Moved Permanently" message. Here is my nginx.conf:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  server {
      listen 80;
      server_name new-server.net;
      server_tokens off;

      location / {
          return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
      }
  }

  server {
      listen 443 ssl;
      server_name           new-server.net;
      server_tokens         off;

      ssl_certificate       /etc/nginx/certs/server.cer;
      ssl_certificate_key   /etc/nginx/certs/server.key;

      location / {
          proxy_pass  http://new-server.net:8081/;
          proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
          proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   https ;
          proxy_redirect      http:// https:// ;
      }
  }

  server {
      listen 8444 ssl;
      server_name old-server.net;
      server_tokens off;

      ssl_certificate       /etc/nginx/certs/server.cer;
      ssl_certificate_key   /etc/nginx/certs/server.key;

      location /devs {
          rewrite ^/devs(.*) https://new-server.net$1 permanent;
      }
  }

}
```

I'm using rewrite because the new server doesn't have the /devs/ context path of the old server. I wasn't sure how to achieve this with a 'return 301' line. So, is it possible for me to allow devs to continue to GET and POST to the old URL and have those requests sent to the new URL?

Comment: tell curl to follow the redirect?

Comment: 1) Tell curl to FOLLOW_LOCATION. 2) Change your 301 to a 307 (this will tell the browser to retry the request, so a POST request will be made again to the new URL; this does not happen with 301).

Comment: I know how to do a command like `return 307 $scheme://new-server.net$request_uri` but that won't account for the fact that the new server does not have the '/devs/' context path. How do I return 307 and remove the '/devs/' context path?